# What was the story with goo that absorbed everything?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading a sci fi comic with a story where there was a goo or ooze that absorbed everything.  I think the goo (or whatever it was) was black.

I remember reading it in the late 70's or early 80's (I was in the UK). There were a number of these comics published with different stories in each. I can't remember if you got more than one story in each issue. I think the comics were maybe about A5 size rather than magazine size.

One of the covers had a space web trapping a ship (a bit like the star trek episode).  I've been searching the web trying to find the name of the publication.  I do remember they were very popular amongst me and my friends at the time.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the comics you're looking for are the [Starblazer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starblazer) series. The one with the web is here:

[image]

There were almost 300 issues, and I'm afraid I've no idea which one had the black goo.

There's a [site with most of the covers](http://www.comicvine.com/starblazer/4050-32432/?page=6&sortBy=asc); if you have a look there, you might find something that rings a bell.

Comment: Thanks! After seeing the covers I'm sure I read a couple of them around about 1979/1980

Comment: I had dozens of these back in the day - I wish I knew where they'd ended up!

Comment: Damit, now I want to read these comics...